# In MySQL, how to pass a set of objects to a stored procedure?

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures

In my C# code, I will be populating a Dictionary.
I need to get that data into a MySQL table in the most efficient way possible.

Is it possible to pass that to a MySQL stored procedure?   I guess I could pass it in some sort of string with commas, etc, so that the stored procedure could then call a function to parse the string and populate the table, but that's a pain.

Any other ideas?

Thanks!

Based on the comments so far, let my try to show the code/sudocode I'm working on.
The code that builds the dictionary will look something like this:

```
        private void DistributeCallsToReschedule()
    {
        CallTimeSpacing = GetNumMinutesInNextCallWindow() / callsToReschedule.Count;

        DateTime currTimeToCall = new DateTime(); 
        foreach (int id in callsToReschedule)   
        {
            CallIdTimeToCallMap.Add(id, currTimeToCall);
            currTimeToCall.AddMinutes(CallTimeSpacing);
        }
    }
```

So, the dictionary can contain my entries.

What I HOPE I can do is to pass the dictionary to a stored procedure as shown below.
If this isn't possible, what's the most efficient way to do what the stored procedure indicates; ie,
the stored procedure wants to have a table to JOIN to, that has the data from the dictonary populated in the C# code.  In other words, what's the most efficient way to get the dictionary's data into a table in MySQL?  If this isn't possible, and I have to loop, what's the most efficient way to do that:  Iteratively call a stored procedure?  Build a prepared statement that has all the values (build via StringBuilder, I suppose)?

PARAMETERS PASSED TO STORED PROCEDURE BY C# CODE:
    @CallIdTimeToCallMap

Put @CallIdTimeToCallMap into CallIdTimeToCallMapTable;

update cr
     set cr.TimeToCall = map.TimeToCall
from callRequest cr
inner join CallIdTimeToCallMapTable map on
     cr.id = map.id

Comment: Why would you use a stored procedure instead of a simple insert statement ?

Comment: You could create a function that takes in a List<T> object and inside of that function have a foreach loop that does the insert also why not just create a simple Insert Stored procedure.. show what you have tried thus far or what you are trying to do via code...

Answer (score 0):

You have to map objects to tables and columns before any relational database can do anything with them.  Objects are not relations.

You don't say what the parameters are that the stored procedure is expecting.

If it's an INSERT or UPDATE that expects a large set of objects, I'd wonder if a stored procedure is the right answer.  You'd have to call it repeatedly, once to write the row for each object in the set.  I'd consider a prepared statement, binding variables, and batching so you can do it in one round trip.

Is the set a single unit of work?  Have you thought about transactional behavior?

Comment: Thanks, duffymo.  The parameter will essentially be a list of objects, where the objects have two fields.  The idea is to insert them into a table, in MySQL, that has these two columns.  I definitely want to make ONE call to the db, so would a prepared statement be more efficient than multiple calls to a sproc (I assume yes, but would like your opinion).  By "batching", what do you mean?  Yes, I will do this within one transaction.

Comment: HTTP doesn't know or care about lists of objects.  Each instance is a row in a table.  You'll have to translate the object data into table and columns and call once per object to INSERT each row.